# bulk insert image from relative path

Tags: sql-server-2005, bulkinsert

I wonder if some can help me out with this little problem. I have the following insert statement:

```
insert into symbol (sy_id, sy_fg_color, sy_bg_color, sy_icon)
select 302, 0, 16245177, sy_icon = (select * from openrowset(bulk 'K:\mypath\icons\myicon.png', single_blob) as image)
```

Is it possible to make the path relative in any way? I'm using TFS to deploy the database, so if it's not possible to make it relative with T-SQL, maybe it can be done with a little help from TFS/Visual Studio deploy?

Comment: No, I have not yet found a solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139245/relative-path-in-t-sql is exactly what you need. There's no straight-foreward answer for this one :(

Comment: You can use UNC in your BulkInsert and set it to a variable first.

Comment: What do you mean by "bulk insert"? A large data item (if so, see answer below), or INSERT multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert into a `varbinary(max)` field using T-SQL using the `OPENROWSET` commmand.

```
INSERT dbo.tblPhotos
(
    LargePhoto
)
SELECT tblPhotos.*
FROM OPENROWSET 
    (BULK 'c:\images\image*.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) ThumbnailPhoto
```

Note that the file path in this case is relative to the targeted SQL server and **not your client** running this command.

Essentially, there are two ways to SELECT a BLOB with TSQL:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Test\Test1.pdf', SINGLE_BLOB) a
```

As well as:

```
SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Test\Test1.pdf', SINGLE_BLOB) a
```

You can then use this to INSERT by doing an INSERT SELECT... or an UPDATE SELECT ...

See more [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1904w6t(VS.80).aspx)