# SQL - insert image from relative path?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a SQL script, that can be transferred to another computer and someone else will get a whole database with no problem.

What I'm fighting with, is how to make a relative path for an image?

Let's say, that someone will have a script in `c:\Documents\script.sql`

But I don't know that if someone will keep it there.

I have a folder with images, that I want to load to my database

So here's a fragment of my script, how to make a relative path? Let's say that images/ and `script.sql` are in the same folder

```
INSERT dbMagazynier.dbo.Produkty (Nazwa, Cena, Opis, Zdjecie, ID_Producenct) 
SELECT 'jeansy', 199.00, 'jenasy jak na zdjeciu', Zdjecie.*, 5 
FROM OPENROWSET  (BULK '\images\jeansy.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) Zdjecie
```

BUT SQL Server 2012 says that it can't find my jeans image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can work with relative paths in SQL Server. You can check more in this question: [Relative path in t sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139245/relative-path-in-t-sql)

The best you can do is to declare a variable at the top of the script, specify the file location there and use your variable later in the code of the script. You can also put some comments about the variable with instructions for people using the script.